# Rails Admin how to show dropdown field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, field, dropdown, rails-admin

I am using Rails Admin gem (Ruby On Rails) and I need to show a dropdown field on one form.

I check about adding Enum method to Class definition from sample [here:](http://thehungrycoder.com/ruby-on-rails/showing-drop-down-list-box-for-a-field-in-railsadmin.html)

But this is not working in my case:
the result I am getting are values inside textbox not in dropdown [image: rails admin].

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Do you have `status` column in your Tests database table ?

Comment: No,  so you think I need to have it also in db ?

Comment: Yes you need it. Otherwise what will be created for create action you are defining. Mean where will the value of `status` be stored when user submits the form.

I have added an answer with a reference to documentation. Please follow

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Enumeration) is an official documentation for Rails Admin Enumeration.

It states that If you already have a database column for which you want a dropdown then simple add a method `COLUM_NNAME_enum` and every thing will be taken care off. e.g

If you want a dropdown for `status` column then you need to define a `status_enum` method in your model.

Other approach is directly telling the `field` that we wanna use `enum` for this field so there are 2  options to do that.

```
 class Test << ActiveRecord::Base

    rails_admin do
      create do 
        field :status , :enum do
          enum_method do
            :status_enum
          end
        end 
      end
    end

    #Here is other simple option

    rails_admin do
      create do 
        field :status , :enum do
          enum do
            [['Actice',1],['Pending',0]]
          end
        end 
      end
    end
  end
```